# Loop within loop coffeescript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

In coffeescript how can I have for loop withing a for loop

I am trying with following code but its not working

```
scale = filenames.length
for key, filename in filenames
    x = key
    for i in [x...scale]
        alert(i)
```

where filenames is an array of filenames

when I try following, it works

```
for key, filename in filenames
    x = key
    for i in [0...scale]
        alert(i)
```

Answer (score 3):

In Coffeescript, the first argument passed to `for ... in` gets populated with the actual `value`, second, optional parameter, is for the `index`.

`x = key` is also not necessary in this code, you can directly refer to `key`.

The result should be as follows:

```
filenames = ['One.txt', 'Two.txt', 'Three.txt'] # a dummy array for testing purposes
scale = filenames.length

# now the actual loop
for filename, key in filenames
    for i in [key...scale]
        alert i
```

See second example in [CoffeeScript - Loops and Comprehensions](http://coffeescript.org/#loops)